# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserProfileController::userClockOut(), 1 passed in, 3 expected

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to work through the below code and it is giving me the error as above in postman. I thought that by storing **AttendanceRecord** in a variable should've sufficed. I wonder what did I do wrong ? Below are the function in my **UserProfileController**, *route* in **api.php** and **web.php**. Please help.

Screenshot of my table in MySQL and migration table code:

```
https://paste.pics/f6103e8822c01f26bd23d500e0b0e9ad  
https://paste.pics/25f8fb016d87113211abfa47e18055d4 
https://paste.pics/008df0256fd5ec20caff3772194cc0cf 
https://paste.pics/66cca657a49944e8087451c3b75967d3
```

```
public function userClockOut(Request $r, $tt, $tt2)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";

        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'date_checkIn', 'time_checkOut', 'location_checkOut'])->first();

        $tt = AttendanceRecord::find($tt);
        $tt2 = AttendanceRecord::find($tt2);

        $tz = $tt->created_at;
        $tz2 = $tt2->updated_at;

        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tz, 'UTC');
        $time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $tz2, 'UTC');
        $date->setTimezone('Asia/Singapore');
        $time->setTimezone('Asia/Singapore');

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkOut = $time;
        $users->location_checkOut = $r->location_checkOut;

        // Save the updated data to the database
        AttendanceRecord::updateOrCreate(
            ['staff_id' => $users->staff_id, 'date_checkIn' => $date],
            $users->toArray()
        );

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

Route in api.php

```
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::get('getdata', [UserProfileController::class, 'getdata']);
Route::post('getdata/{id}', [UserProfileController::class, 'showdata']);
Route::post('adduser', [UserProfileController::class, 'adddata']);
Route::delete('deleteuser', [UserProfileController::class, 'deleteuser']);
Route::PUT('updateuser', [UserProfileController::class, 'updateuser']);
Route::post('updateuserClockIn',   [UserProfileController::class, 'userClockIn']);
Route::post('updateuserClockOut', [UserProfileController::class, 'userClockOut']);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Route in web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DataFeedController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;

Route::redirect('/', 'login');

// Register new staff
Route::get('register', [UserController::class, 'create'])->name('register');
Route::post('register', [UserController::class, 'store']);

// User list, view profile and update profile
Route::get('users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('users/profile/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
Route::get('users/profile/edit/{id}', [UserController::class, 'edit']);
Route::post('users/profile/edit/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
Route::get('history', [UserController::class, 'history']);

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {

    // Route for the getting the data feed
    Route::get('/json-data-feed', [DataFeedController::class, 'getDataFeed'])->name('json_data_feed');

    Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::fallback(function () {
        return view('pages/utility/404');
    });
});
```

Comment: Show your route and how you use it.

Comment: @SemihSAHIN i updated my code above, please have a look

Answer (score 2):

Based on the way you define the method, you should revise your route as follows:

```
Route::post('updateuserClockOut/{tt}/{tt2}', [UserProfileController::class, 'userClockOut']);
```

And in postman you can perform a post request like this (example):
**http:://yoursite/updateuserClockOut/13/102**
Or to keep the route the same but send the parameters as request parameters, you can do this:

```
public function userClockOut(Request $r)
{
    $tt = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt);
    $tt2 = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt2);
    // ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: what if Ijust wanted it to remain with only like this :

**http:://yoursite/updateuserClockOut** ,

should i edit my code in **userClockOut** function like this ?
$tt = AttendanceRecord::find($tt);

$tz = $tt->created_at;
$tz2 = $tt->updated_at;

$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tz, 'UTC');
$time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $tz2, 'UTC');

Comment: @Jabss Ok, in that case you can send these two parameters in request parameters and you should remove them from the method.

Comment: So my function will be, public function **userClockOut** (Request $r, Request $tt, Request $tt2) ?

Comment: No, just `Request $r` is sufficient.

Comment: That means, my code in **userClockOut** function like this ? $tt = AttendanceRecord::find($tt); $tz = $r->created_at; $tz2 = $r->updated_at; $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tz, 'UTC'); $time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $tz2, 'UTC'); ?

Comment: To get `$tt` variable you have to do `$r->tt`. So like that: `$tt = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt);`

Comment: I've edited my code to the following, $tt = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt); $tt2 = AttendanceRecord::find($r->tt2); and now it is saying 'Attempt to read property &quot;created_at&quot; on null' . Why does this happen ? the created_at column exist and it should've referred to the same date_checkIn and staff_id . as shown in my AttendanceRecord::updateOrCreate() below

Comment: @Jabss are you sure the relevant values ​​exist in the record?

Comment: just for your information, in my migration table, attendance_records, I'm using $table->timestamps() and there are no 'created_at' or 'updated_at' column. also, I'm using Carbon::now() in my other **userClockIn** function. could it be the case that both the columns are not able to be detected because of the Carbon::now() ?

Comment: `$table->timestamps();` Adds **created_at** and **updated_at** columns. See also: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns

Comment: I included a screenshot of the database table and also code in my migration table in my post above, please have a look

Comment: I included another 2 more screenshots to see more clearly on the table and on the display page

Comment: >> `Attempt to read property &quot;created_at&quot; on null`

This means that the `$tt` variable (result) is null.
Use one of Laravel's debug functions to find out the contents of the `$tt` variable.
For example: you can use: `dd($tt);`, just to see what's in there.

Take a look at this:
```$tt = AttendanceRecord::find($tt);```. There is also a function called `findOrFail()`. Try that one when finding a record.

Try to solve the problems 1 step at a time. I would solve the finding of the `$tt` record first.

Answer (score 1):

when you use vars in controller method, laravel considers this vars as url segments!
it means that your route must change into:

```
Route::post('updateuserClockOut/{tt}/{tt2}', [UserProfileController::class, 'userClockOut']);
```

or if maybe you change them in method to have default values:

```
public function userClockOut(Request $r, $tt = null, $tt2 = null)
```

or even nullable them in route:

```
{tt?}/{tt2?}
```

Comment: what if Ijust wanted it to remain with only like this :

**http:://yoursite/updateuserClockOut** ,

should i edit my code in **userClockOut** function like this ?
$tt = AttendanceRecord::find($tt);

$tz = $tt->created_at;
$tz2 = $tt->updated_at;

$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tz, 'UTC');
$time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $tz2, 'UTC');

Comment: @Jabss you have to check them wheter is null or not (second approach). `if ($tt !=null) ...`